# Related to boolean operations

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have come across the following code:

```
const bool isIntersect = ...;
const bool isReversed = ...
if(!isIntersect != isReversed) {
  //some stuff
}
```

It is very weird for me. The question is can be it written in more clear way:
So seems it is not as `!isIntersect || isIntersect` nor `!isIntersect && isIntersect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's draw a *truth table*:

```
isIntersect isReversed outcome
      false      false    true
      false       true   false
       true      false   false 
       true       true    true
```

As we can see, it's just an *equivalence*:

```
isIntersect == isReversed
```

So you can simplify the code into

```
if (isIntersect == isReversed) {
  // some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isIntersect == isReversed) {
```

should be the same.

To represent it without an (in)equality operator, you'd need the negation of XOR,

```
if(!(isIntersect ^ isReversed)) {
```

but that's hardly clearer.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the four outcome scenarios:**

*Scenario 1*

```
const bool isIntersect = true;
const bool isReversed = true;
if(!isIntersect != isReversed) {
  // DOES RUN => ((!true) != true) => (false != true) => true
}
```

*Scenario 2*

```
const bool isIntersect = true;
const bool isReversed = false;
if(!isIntersect != isReversed) {
  // DOES NOT RUN => ((!true) != false) => (false != false) => false
}
```

*Scenario 3*

```
const bool isIntersect = false;
const bool isReversed = true;
if(!isIntersect != isReversed) {
  // DOES NOT RUN => ((!false) != true) => (true != true) => false
}
```

*Scenario 4*

```
const bool isIntersect = false;
const bool isReversed = false;
if(!isIntersect != isReversed) {
  // DOES RUN => ((!false) != false) => (true != false) => true
}
```

**This gives us the following *truth table*:**

```
isIntersect   isReversed   outcome
==================================
      false        false      true
      false         true     false
       true        false     false
       true         true      true
```

**Therefore the code in the aforementioned `if-statement` either runs:**

- IF `isIntersect` AND `isReversed` ARE BOTH `true`

*OR*

- IF `isIntersect` AND `isReversed` ARE BOTH `false`

**Can be understood like this:**

```
if((isIntersect && isReversed) || (!isIntersect && !isReversed)) { ... }
```

**Simplified using De Morgan's Theorem:**

```
if((isIntersect && isReversed) || !(isIntersect || isReversed)) { ... }
// May be more difficult to understand it this way
```

**Simplest Form Statement:**

```
if (isIntersect == isReversed) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The test is testing whether `isIntersected` and `isReversed` are both true or both false, so a more verbose (but maybe easier to understand) way of testing it would be

```
if ((isIntersected && isReversed) || (!isIntersected && !isReversed))
```